# replace nth occurrence of character in a file using awk regardless of the line

Tags: replace, awk

I am trying to replace the nth occurrence of a character or string regardless of the line using awk.

So if our data was this

```
|||||||
||||||
|||||
|||
```

and we were trying to replace | with A

then the output should look like this, assuming we want to replace every 3rd occurance

```
||A||A|
|A||A|
|A||A
||A
```

The current awk command I am using is this

```
 awk '/|/{c++;if(c==3){sub(/|/,"A");c=0}}1' test.data
```

and it wrongly outputs this

```
|||||||
||||||
A||||
|||
```

also the data can look like this

```
|||xfsafrwe|||asfasdf|
|safasf|||asfasdf||
||asfasf|||
|||
```

and the result of course is this

```
||Axfsafrwe||Aasfasdf|
|safasfA||asfasdfA|
|Aasfasf||A
||A
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '{
  for (i = 0; ++i <= NF;)
    ++c % n || $i = v 
  }1' OFS= FS= n=3 v=A infile
```

Adjusted after OP clarification:

```
awk '{
  for (i = 0; ++i <=NF;)
    if ($i == o)
      ++C % c || $i = n 
  } 1' FS= OFS= c=3 o=\| n=A infile
```

Comment: that worked for the first case I gave above, but it not the right solution.  I need to work in terms replacing nth occurrences for a string like "|".  I gave another example above.

Comment: @ppone,
I've added a new version.

Comment: awk '{
  c=0; for (i = 0; ++i <= NF;){
    if( $i == v){c++;if(c%3==0){ $i = l }} }
  }1' OFS= FS= n=3 v=a l=c test.data

Comment: I came up with the above based on your solution.  But you already beat me to the punch with a more concise one.  :)

Comment: It's worth explicitly mentioning that splitting a string into characters by using a null value for `FS` is undefined behavior per POSIX and so while some awks such as gawk will do what you want, other awks won't, e.g. some will ignore the `FS` setting. For portability use `for (i=1;i<=length($0);i++) substr($0,i,1)` instead of `FS="" ... for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i`.