# Awk to replace a value in the header with the value next to it?

Tags: awk, replace

I have a compressed text file (chrall.txt.gz)  that looks like this. It has a header line with pairs of IDs for each individual. E.g. 1032 AND 468768 are IDs for one individual. There are 1931 individuals in the file, therefore 3862 IDs in total. Each  pair corresponds to one individual. E.g. the next individual would be 1405 468769 etc....

After the header is 21465139 lines. I am not interested in the lines/body of the  file. Just the header

```
misc SNP pos A2 A1 1032 468768 1405 468769 1564 468770 1610 468771 998 468774 975 468775 1066 468776 1038 468778 1275 468781 999 468782 976 468783 1145 468784 1141 468786 1280 468789 910 468790 978 468791 1307 468792 ...

--- rs1038757:1072:T:TA 1072 TA T 1.113 0.555 1.612 0.519 0.448 0.653 1.059 0.838 1.031 0.518 1.046 0.751 1.216 1.417 1.008 0.917 0.64 1.04 1.113 1.398 1.173 0.956 …
```

I want to replace every first ID of one pair e.g. 1032, 1405, 1564, 1610, 998, 975 with the ID next to it. So every 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ID etc... is replaced to the ID next to it.
So it looks like this:

```
misc SNP pos A2 A1 468768 468768 468769 468769 468770 468770 468771 468771 468774 468774 468775 468775 468776 468776 468778 468778 468781 468781 468782 468782 468783 468783 468784 468784 468786 468786 468789 468789 468790 468790 468791 468791 468792 468792 

etc..
```

I am completely stumped on how to do this. My guess is use awk/gsub and replace every nth occurrence 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 to the value next to it...Also need to ignore this bit **misc SNP pos A2 A1**

My working out:

Read first line and ignore first 5 fields:

```
awk FNR==1'{ $1=""; $2=""; $3=""; $4=""; $5="";}'
```

Someone used this code to replace the 3rd occurence to A. I am assuming I replace the 3 to 2 as I want to replace every 2 occurrence but the only problem is I also want to replace the first ID as well...

```
awk '{ c=0; for (i = 0; ++i <= NF;){ if( $i == v){c++;if(c%3==0){ $i = l }} } }1' OFS= FS= n=3 v=a l=c
```

[replace nth occurrence of character in a file using awk regardless of the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961416/replace-nth-occurrence-of-character-in-a-file-using-awk-regardless-of-the-line)

I am not sure how to adapt it to mine...

Comment: You're making odd assumptions about awk syntax - it's mostly just like C or any other Algol-based language. Get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn how to write awk scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to replace the first 5 fields then just don't include them in the loop by starting it at 6, and if you want to replace every 2nd field then just increment the loop variable by 2 on each iteration:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{for (i=6;i<NF;i+=2) $i=$(i+1)} 1' file
misc SNP pos A2 A1 468768 468768 468769 468769 468770 468770 468771 468771 468774 468774 468775 468775 468776 468776 468778 468778 468781 468781 468782 468782 468783 468783 468784 468784 468786 468786 468789 468789 468790 468790 468791 468791 468792 468792 ...

--- rs1038757:1072:T:TA 1072 TA T 1.113 0.555 1.612 0.519 0.448 0.653 1.059 0.838 1.031 0.518 1.046 0.751 1.216 1.417 1.008 0.917 0.64 1.04 1.113 1.398 1.173 0.956 …
```

Comment: This worked thanks. Can you please tell me what the code means for future reference. thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. It;s absolutely basic awk, we can't explain awk fundamentals in every answer and I already stated in the first paragraph what the overall approach is so please just look at the man page (if you have to - I bet you could even just guess at what the constructs mean and get it right) and let me know if you have any specific questions afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> {m,g}awk -F'^.+[A-Za-z][0-9]+ +[0-9]+ +' '!_<NR ||
>
> $!NF = sprintf("%.*s%s%.0s",(___ = substr($_,++_,-_+index($!_, $++_)))* \
>         sub("[ ]*[^ ]+ *$",_="",___) * sub("^"(__="[0-9]+"),"_",$!(NF = NF)),
>        gsub(" "__" "," ")*gsub("_",_)*gsub(" "__,"&&"), ___$_,FS="^$")' OFS=' _'
> ```

```
misc SNP pos A2 A1 468768 468768 468769 468769 468770 468770 468771 468771 468774 468774 468775 468775 468776 468776 468778 468778 468781 468781 468782 468782 468783 468783 468784 468784 468786 468786 468789 468789 468790 468790 468791 468791 468792 468792
    
--- rs1038757:1072:T:TA 1072 TA T 1.113 0.555 1.612 0.519 0.448 0.653 1.059 0.838 1.031 0.518 1.046 0.751 1.216 1.417 1.008 0.917 0.64 1.04 1.113 1.398 1.173 0.956 …
```